# mdk5:"""error: #5: cannot open source input file "cmsis_gcc.h" """

Tags: motorola-emdk

I've just started using mdk5, created a new project and the first example compiles with an error """... ... \Drivers\CMSIS\Include\cmsis_compiler.h(41): error: #5: cannot open source input file “cmsis_gcc.h”: No such file or directory" "", but I see the same file in the official routine as in the "cmsis_compiler.h" file I imported
I'm not sure how to solve this error

```
#ifndef __CMSIS_COMPILER_H
#define __CMSIS_COMPILER_H

#include <stdint.h>

/*
 * Arm Compiler 6 (armclang)
 */
#if defined (__ARMCC_VERSION) && (__ARMCC_VERSION >= 6010050)
  #include "cmsis_armclang.h"


/*
 * GNU Compiler
 */
#elif defined ( __GNUC__ )
  #include "cmsis_gcc.h"


/*
 * IAR Compiler
 */
#elif defined ( __ICCARM__ )
  #include <cmsis_iccarm.h>
```

I'm looking forward to the big boys answering my little questions as a newbie